# How to "vectorize" a function in Rust

Tags: rust, closures

Suppose that I want to take a function that operates on two elements of a collection and turn it into a function that operates on two collections elementwise.

For example, I want to turn a function adding two numbers together into a function that takes two collections of numbers and adds the numbers up elementwise. In order to do this without code repetition, I tried to implement a function which takes in closures:

```rust
fn vectorize<F, H, U, J>(f: F) -> impl Fn(H, H) -> J
where
    F: FnMut((H::Item, H::Item)) -> U,
    H: IntoIterator,
    J: FromIterator<U>
    { |x, y| {x.into_iter().zip(y).map(f).collect()} }
```

The comipler gives:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `f`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:10:40
   |
5  | fn vectorize<F, H, U, J>(f: F) -> impl Fn(H, H) -> J
   |                          - captured outer variable
...
10 |     { |x, y| {x.into_iter().zip(y).map(f).collect()} }
   |       ------                           ^ move occurs because `f` has type `F`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |       |
   |       captured by this `Fn` closure
```

This does not work because the closure `f` is moved out of the returned closure by the `map` method. But really, such a function should be possible to write, since the `f` is `FnMut` and will be valid no matter how many times it is used on different iterators.

How can I write this type of function so that it does not cause such errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to change three things here.

1. You can't convert a `FnMut` into a `Fn` so you have to return `impl FnMut` as well.
2. Add `move` before the closure so it takes ownership of `f`
3. You can't pass `f` to map, because that necesarily moves it, but you can't move from a closure that only implements `Fn` as in your code or `FnMut` as in the fixed code. Instead pass a reference to it (only a mutable reference [also implements `FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html#impl-FnMut%3CA%3E-for-%26mut+F) and to pass a mutable reference you have to make `f` mutable as well):

```rust
fn vectorize<F, H, U, J>(mut f: F) -> impl FnMut(H, H) -> J
where
    F: FnMut((H::Item, H::Item)) -> U,
    H: IntoIterator,
    J: FromIterator<U>,
{
    move |x, y| x.into_iter().zip(y).map(&mut f).collect()
}
```

You might also want to add a second `: IntoIterator` type parameter so you can merge 2 different types of collections with possibly distinct types as well.

Comment: Why does ```f``` need to be mutable in this case? Also, would this function consume x and y once they have been moved into the closure?

Comment: 1) see my edit, 2) Yes, but that's no different from any other closure, specifically that's not changed wether or not you add `move`, that's just how function parameters work [as explained in *The Book*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ownership-and-functions).