# How to make a verctorized function out of a scalar function in rust?

Tags: function, generics, rust

I want to make neural networks in rust. The sizes of the vectors and matrices will be rather small, e.g. 16 or 32 elements in one dimension. I want to give as much information to the compiler as possible in order have it do as many optimizations as possible.

One primitive when building neural networks are vectorized functions, i.e. functions which act on a vector, but which process every element of the vector as a scalar, indepedently of the other elements of the vector. Examples are [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) or [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

I think that for vectorizing a scalar function, e.g. the scalar function ReLU, it would be good to have a generic function, that takes a scalar function and makes a vectorized function out of it. Here is my idea of the code:

```
fn relu_scalar(x: f32) {
    std::cmp::max(x, 0)
}

// shall allow vectorization of any scalar function f32 -> f32
fn vectorized<ScalarFn, const SIZE: usize>(inp: &[f32; SIZE], out: &mut [f32; SIZE]) {
    for i in 0..SIZE {
        out[i] = ScalarFn(inp[i]);  // compiler error: expected function, tuple struct or tuple variant, found type parameter `ScalarFn`
    }
}

fn main() {
    let inp = [0.7f32; 32];
    inp[5] = -3.;

    let out = [0.0f32; 32];

    vectorized<relu_scalar>(inp, out);

    print!(out);
}
```

However, this does not compile. The error is marked in the code.

Comment: You need to constrain the function with `where ScalarFn: FnMut(f32) -> f32`, and [this was already told to you in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77034679/7884305).

Comment: Apply the syntactic suggestions of the compiler, and after you will decide if you have a more specific question. In this simple case, you could remove the `ScalarFn` generic parameter, and use a `fnct: fn(f32) -> f32` parameter as third argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "vectorize" a function in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77020456/how-to-vectorize-a-function-in-rust)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman as you are well aware what I've been told, there is no point in telling me again. Your comment is useless and inappropriate. Besides that, SO is not for displaying your smartness or superiority. It's for generating good Q&A pairs. If you can't contribute to that, then don't contribute at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

any thing inside `<...>` should be a type, you are trying to pass an actual instance of a function to the generic, instead you will need to pass `Fn(f32)->f32` which is a trait

there are two way I can think of

1. specify the trait, pass the function
2. pass the function pointer

```
// the scalar version the relu function
fn relu(x: f32) -> f32 { // <-- added type return annotation
    0_f32.max(x) // <-- change since f32 doesn't impl Ord, can't use cmp::max
}

//             V-- this is only a generic type annotation
fn vectorized1<F, const SIZE: usize>(inp: &[f32; SIZE], out: &mut [f32; SIZE], op: F)
    // you need to actually pass the function for it to know which func to use ^
where
    F: Fn(f32) -> f32, // <-- to give it a bound, aka the trait that you will use
{
    for i in 0..SIZE {
        out[i] = op(inp[i]); // <-- since you give the bound at where statement, 
        //the compiler will know it must be a Fn(f32)->f32
    }
}

fn vectorized2<const SIZE: usize>(
    inp: &[f32; SIZE],
    out: &mut [f32; SIZE],
    op: Box<dyn Fn(f32) -> f32>, // <-- you can always just pass the function pointer
) {
    for i in 0..SIZE {
        out[i] = op(inp[i]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut inp = [0.7f32; 32];
    inp[5] = -3.;

    let mut out1 = [0.0f32; 32];
    let mut out2 = [0.0f32; 32];

    vectorized1(&inp, &mut out1, relu);
    vectorized2(&inp, &mut out2, Box::new(relu));

    println!("{:?}\n", out1);
    println!("{:?}\n", out2);
}
```